# CakePHP 2.1.x - Run a query without any models in AppController

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I am trying to run a query in AppController on a table that has no Model associated with it. I don't want to use a Model cause this query would fire on every request and I guess using a Model would make it a bit slower.

I found out in one forum that this can be achieved with the following code in CakePHP 1.3

```
$db = ConnectionManager::getInstance();
$conn = $db->getDataSource('default');
$conn->rawQuery($some_sql);
```

But this is not working in CakePHP 2.1.3.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks :)

Comment: using a model doenst make it any slower if you run just a query (using query() of the model)

Comment: What exactly do you need to get from the database on every request?
This also means doing a database request for each and every request to the application. This would increase DB load. If you're loading some configuration it may be better to load it from a file and "Objectifying" it.

Comment: To retrive your sql-query's data in this context, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/21612950/287948

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The `getDataSource()` method is static in `CakePHP 2.x`, so you should be able to use:

```
App::uses('ConnectionManager', 'Model');
    
$db = ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default');
$db->rawQuery($some_sql);
```

Comment: i did the same thing bit shows me the error message which is mentioned below. Only variables should be assigned by reference. can you tell me that what changes still i have to do ?

Comment: You may need `App::uses('ConnectionManager', 'Model');` as well

Comment: Any way to do this with prepared statements?

Comment: I tried this using CakePHP 2.6.3 and it only returned an object with the query, but not the result. Instead, I used 
$model->query('SELECT * FROM table'); That gave me the result I expected.

Comment: second line will be `$db->fetchAll($sql);` for getting result directly.

Comment: THANK YOU `DHOFSTET` AND `RICHARD`, your suggestions worked for me to solve my issue :)

Answer (score 9):

you should run this way

```
    App::uses('ConnectionManager', 'Model'); 
    $db = ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default');
    if (!$db->isConnected()) {
       $this->Session->setFlash(__('Could not connect to database.'), 'default',            array('class' => 'error'));
    } else {
        $db->rawQuery($some_sql);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

rawQuery will not return data, use $db->query instead.

```
App::uses('ConnectionManager', 'Model');

$db = ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default');
$data = $db->query($some_sql);
```