# how to write complex sub query in cake php i.e sub query is in from clause

Tags: cakephp-2.0

```
SELECT AM.m, 
COUNT(JRC.id) FROM 
(SELECT 1 AS m 
   UNION ALL SELECT 2
   UNION ALL SELECT 3 
   UNION ALL SELECT 4 
   UNION ALL SELECT 5 
   UNION ALL SELECT 6
   UNION ALL SELECT 7
   UNION ALL SELECT 8
   UNION ALL SELECT 9
   UNION ALL SELECT 10
   UNION ALL SELECT 11
   UNION ALL SELECT 12
) AS AM
LEFT JOIN `candidates` AS `JRC`
ON   AM.m = MONTH(JRC.created) AND (JRC.jr_id = 58)
GROUP BY AM.m
```

it will result month wise user count for 12 months

Answer (score 0):

Taken from this answer:
[CakePHP 2.1.x - Run a query without any models in AppController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11048293/cakephp-2-1-x-run-a-query-without-any-models-in-appcontroller)

```
$db = ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default');
$db->rawQuery($some_sql);
```

(Also, I would suggest you refer to this as a "derived table" not a sub-query.  It may seem like a trivial comment but it will probably help you find a more applicable answer.)