# Cake 2.X retrive data from rawQuery

Tags: cakephp-2.0

As show at  [CakePHP 2.1.x - Run a query without any models in AppController](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11048293)
I have a query,

```
 $q = "select id from table where id=123";
 $db = ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default');
 $qr = $db->rawQuery($q);
```

ok (!), it works... But, how to get my data?? Where the tutorial examples?

I need something like `$data = $qr->fetchAll()` method  or `$id = getMyData($qr)` function.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe this may be the solution or at least a point in the right direction.

```
$q = "select id from table where id=123";
$db = ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default');
$myData = $db->query($q);
```

Comment: Not worked, getting error `Fatal error: Class 'ConnectionManager' not found`